# Handling Transaction Between Paypal and Local Datasase

Tags: database, transactions, paypal, distributed-transactions

What is the best practice to handle transaction between application and paypal.

Consider:

- I'm Alice and I want send money to Bob
- In my DB I see that Bob has $200 and I want to send him $150.
- Once transaction is sent I want to update the Bob's account such that it would contain $50.

Now according to PayPal API I can send Pay and receive success. However what happens
if I for example send Pay it succeeds but I fail to receive a response due to network problem. So I assume that error happened and try again and technically I'll send $300 to Bob instead of $150?

How can I handle such a transaction - between a local database that keeps an account and the remote PayPal API?

Answer (score 6):

**I had this exact concern recently with an ASP.NET MVC project I was completing for a client.**

I learned two things:

- Communication between Paypal and your database cannot be trusted (well, didn't really learn this, but it was entirely reinforced)
- I now understand why so many websites that have Paypal as a transaction type mention there could be a processing period between the time that the transaction was completed and shipping/delivery of the product is completed.

---

*The way you handle the situation is similar to the way a business could handle personal checks:*

- A personal check looks like currency (and typically is), but many businesses would like some sort of verification from the bank that funds are available before they accept payment - so they use a machine that asks the bank if funds are actually available.
- If the machine says the funds are available, the business trusts it and you complete the transaction.  **However**, the machine can give an error message that typically means "the funds are not available or something went wrong" and the business has a decision to make:

  - We can trust the customer and accept the check, deliver the product, and hope for the best when later depositing the check to the bank.
  - Or we can tell the customer that it will take time for the check to clear, deposit the check, wait for the funds to actually arrive in our account, and (if successful) deliver the product after the business receives funding.

This sounds inefficient with the way many businesses operate today, but it is something that does come up.  In fact, this is why a lot of businesses stray away from accepting personal checks, they are unreliable when compared to other methods of payment.

*Now how does this correlate to handling a Paypal payment?*

- A Paypal payment looks like currency (and it typically is), but many businesses would like some sort of verification from the Paypal that funds are available before they accept payment - so they use Paypal PDT, IPN, or other method for checking that the transaction was handled appropriately.
- If Paypal properly responds to one of the verification requests, the business can trust it and complete the transaction.  **However**, your website may throw an error of some sort (i.e. Paypal could reply with an IPN response of `NOTVALID`, or you could never get a reply from Paypal).  The business has a decision to make:

  - The business can trust the customer and accept that they have made a Paypal payment and everything should be alright (*very bad decision in the case of a Paypal transaction*)
  - Or the business can tell the customer at check-out time that there may be a 72 hour processing period for Paypal payments.

This may not sound like the best way to operate your business, but it is the way we have to deal with an imperfect internet.

### I would set up the Paypal payment flow similar to this:

1. UserA wants to send $100 to another UserB using Paypal
2. UserA enters the value in the 'checkout field' and is sent over to Paypal to verify the transaction.
3. UserA is sent back to your website from Paypal and your website performs the IPN check with the details that Paypal has POSTed to your site(I chose IPN in this case - as if we were using [Express Checkout](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted) as opposed to some other payment gateway that Paypal offers).
4. If the IPN is `VALID`, process the transaction as expected.
5. If the IPN is not `VALID`, mention to the customer that there may be a delay in processing, have your application send you a notification that a possible Paypal transaction issue has occurred (you may want to include a reference id so that you can quickly find which transaction this notification is referencing), and mark the transaction as `pending` as opposed to `complete` or something similar.
6. An admin of the site who handles these notifications will manually investigate the transaction (or force the website to check with Paypal again - see the Paypal API documentation for details on this) and manually mark the transaction as `complete` or `failed`.
7. Notify those involved of the status of the transaction.

It is annoying that we have to have extra steps involved to make sure the money was transferred, but, as mentioned earlier, we are using an imperfect system and we want to be very certain of the success / failure of financial transactions.

An added bonus to this process is that there is likely to be notifications when someone is tampering with the Paypal payment system - leaving you better equipped to deal with evil-doers in the future.

Comment: See, I'm not looking into situation where in PayPal interface I see that the transaction is pending or rejected (because user declined to pay or refused to receive money) - I'll see it and I'll know what happens. I'm looking into situation where I want to make sure that for example payment or invoice was successefully sent regardless the user response.

Comment: I understand, that's why once a transaction is initiated you would set the transaction as pending until Paypal replies with Approved or Denied (either instantly after the transaction is completed, or later when you routinely poll Paypal with your pending transactions to see if any of them are approved or denied), or an Admin manually approves the transaction.  You will not see on Paypal that the transaction is pending or rejected - that will be on your site within your own database and that value will depend on Paypal's responses to your IPN (or other method's) requests.

Comment: I had awarded this answer as it was the most complete one, other that that it does not fully answer my question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link ,Hope PayPal Authorization & Capture method will be suitable for you ,since you don't want lose the response as well as miscalculated amount transfers, PayPal provides correlation id that can be referred for PayPal to confirm your order status,it will be better to pass the order id to PayPal API.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_admin_authcapture

http://www.scribd.com/doc/6303345/40/CorrelationID-for-Reporting-Problems-to-PayPal

Good Luck!

Comment: The correlation ID should *NOT* be used to confirm order status in any way. The correlation ID changes with each request and is only meant for reporting issues.

Comment: Yes correct if we have any issues .Correlation id can be referred

Answer (score 0):

This is known as 2-phase commit. As long as paypal does not participate in the same transaction, you will run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would debit Alice the $150 and reflect the transaction is ***"Pending Confirmation"***, then periodically poll PayPal to synchronize your DB, since you have no control of when the network or PayPal may be available, post, reverse or adjust the transaction. Once PayPal processes the transaction, you can change the status in your DB from "Pending" to "Completed". BTW, this how bank accounts and credit cards are processed. You could apply a double-entry accounting method to your DB. (see this [Q&A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479800/double-entry-accrual-accounting-concept/11480209#11480209)

Answer (score -1):

From what i see you need to make sure the transaction is complete otherwise nothing should be done .

If you deposit the money into PayPal API and you do not receive an response from PAYPAL API then you need to rollback the transaction in you DB.

Comment: What if I for example send a request move $10 to bob, but the _connection_ was lost or incomplete on the response. You can't really know if PayPal's side detected a problem. So I may get an error but from PayPal's POV it was completed successfully.