# Paypal - How to buy audio using PayPal and download the file immediately after

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, paypal

Perhaps someone using PayPal can advise me on the best way to implement the following situation.

I'm developing a website for a non-profit organization and right now we are already setup w/ PayPal and have a "Donate" button on the main page.  The website has audio samples and we would like to provide the option for the user to buy the full audio via PayPay.  This is nontraditional (at least to me) in the sense that we are providing the purchased audio files for download immediately after payment.

Also, note that there is a lot of Audio files and, if not too difficult, we would like to keep track of sales on each item purchased.

How should I design/implement this situation, while using PayPal.

(On a separate note, in the future I would like to keep track of Users and "who purchases which items", so that in case something "bad" happened during the audio download, the user would have the chance to re-retrieve the downloaded item.)

Technology:  ASP.NET 4 (MVC 3)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Paypal Express Checkout that verifies using Paypal's IPN.

This is a long answer and it is best that I point you in the direction of the above and ask that you look up the documentation itself.

Things to keep in mind:

- There are more checkout methods aside from Paypal's Express Checkout, don't get these mixed up when you are looking through the documentation.
- Some of the Paypal ASP.NET code examples were out of date when I last implemented this (about 3 weeks ago)

---

This tutorial was quite valuable when I was going through this process.

Code: http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/10/11/mvcstore-part-22
Video: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-22-restructuring-rerouting-and-paypal

---

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595626/1026898) in reference to the check-out process workflow.  The main idea is that you will need to verify values using Paypal's IPN.  [Here is the documentation](https://www.paypal.com/ipn/).

---

In it's simplest form::

- You're going to need to assign order id's of some sort to each transaction.
- If the payment for the order is not-confirmed (your default state), do not allow download of the mp3.
- If the payment for the order is confirmed, allow download of the mp3.

Keep track of all this information and more in your database and create an Admin section of your app that allows you to view / edit details of all orders.

Comment: Express Checkout (EC) can use Instant Payment Notifications (IPN), but it doesn't use it inherently. In fact, EC makes using IPN unnecessary.

Comment: How does it make it unnecessary?

Comment: Because - for instant payment methods such as credit cards at least - you will already receive a `PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed` in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment API response.

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend using PayPal Digital Goods for Express Checkout (if available in your country); www.paypal.com/digitalgoods

Comment: With all this being said, you can still use IPN, but it is very unnecessary with EC; except in the case of e-check payments. I could go over every minute detail here in this comment, but just know that for digital goods, the only thing you need is SetEC, DoEC and a few validation checks with your database. The PayPal part being only the SetEC and DoEC.

Comment: You don't even really need to use Express Checkout for this situation.  Using PayPal Payments Standard (HTML forms) and IPN or PDT (if you use PDT, you should also use IPN) should work fine too.